# FTP upload not working with Windows 7 scheduler

Tags: batch-file, ftp, scheduled-tasks

I have a .bat file on my Win-7 that uploads a file via FTP to a remote location.
Works perfectly when I double click it.
But when running it via a scheduled task I get "Access denied" and it can't find the FTP program.

My batch file :

```
@Echo Off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set _my_Current_Folder=C:\VEHADARTA\Routine_Tasks\T001_Daily_Changes
    Set _FTPServerName=84.95.247.239
    Set _UserName=XXXX
    Set _Password=YYYY
    Set _RemoteFolder=public_html/vehadarta/Batch_Jobs/
    Set _Filename=Daily_Changes.sql
    Set _ScriptFile=ftp1

    call :Put_the_Daily_Changes_sql_file_in_FTP_Server
    pause
    exit

:Put_the_Daily_Changes_sql_file_in_FTP_Server
     >"%_ScriptFile%" Echo verbose
    >>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo open %_FTPServerName%
    >>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_UserName%
    >>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_Password%
    >>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo cd %_RemoteFolder%
    >>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo lcd %_Current_Folder%
    >>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo prompt
    >>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo binary
    >>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo put %_Filename%
    >>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo quit
    :: Run script
    ftp -s:"%_ScriptFile%"
    Del "%_ScriptFile%"
    exit /b
```

Running it via the scheduled task, I get "**Access is denied**" and also "**Could not find C:\Windows\system32\ftp1**" (changing **ftp1** to **ftp** got same results) :

[image]

**Note** : When running the same scheduler-task on my Win-10 - it works fine.

Would appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheduled tasks run from C:\Windows\System32, and you don't have permission to create files there.

Add `cd "%~dp0"` to the start of your code under `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to move to where the script is currently located before you begin doing things.

Also, don't call the script ftp.bat, since `ftp` is already a command.